# OL 2.10 Text layer

Tags: openlayers-2

I heard that the latest version of openlayers 2.10 text layer provides a    new feature of defining user specified attributes and so I want to give radius values under column radius, but even the latest 2.10 documentation doesn't contain anything about this... can anyone provide any information about this

Comment: Have you seen this exemple : http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html ?

Answer (score 1):

OpenLayers is just about to release 2.12.

There are a couple examples with text layers:

- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/dynamic-text-layer.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/markersTextLayer.html